# BigInteger class with non-ascii characters in Java

Tags: java, string, biginteger

I've been working on a little application which grabs strings embedded within a picture, which in turn are used to calculate 2 big integers for use in a key exchange system. However, when I try and read the strings from a properties file, and implement them into a bigint:

```
String primeStr = "ekoeaokimcgmigcqu{uq{y}sw}ywsAEKOEAOKIMCGMIGCQU[_UQ_[Y]SW]YWS!%+/%!/+)-#'-)'#15;?51?;9=37=973"
BigInteger prime = new BigInteger(this.primeStr,10);
```

I'm thrown an error about the string not being correct. My question is how would I solve the issue so I can use that string within the app?

Comment: You are passing a string of gibberish into the constructor.  What do you expect this code to do?

Comment: You need to translate the text into binary or a number first. There is no standard way to convert your string into an integer.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting Adil-H? Don't use "this" if you are using a variable that's not a field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `String` constructor of `BigInteger` expects a *number*, if your `primeStr` variable somehow encodes a number you'll have to decode it first before passing it to `BigInteger`.